# IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configuration root that contains xxx on FileProvider.getUriForFile

Tags: android, filepath, illegalargumentexception, android-fileprovider

I have been trying to follow the [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html) on sharing files.
I set up the `FileProvider` like this:

On the main manifest xml:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.mysecondapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

the res/xml/filpaths.xml file:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="myexternalimages" path="SpCars_album/" />
</paths>
```

And in my code I am trying the following:

```
File requestFile = new File(mImageFilenames[position]);
                try {
                    fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            SeventhActivity.this,
                            "com.example.mysecondapp.fileprovider",
                            requestFile);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.e("File Selector",
                            "The selected file can't be shared: " +
                                    mImageFilenames[position]);
                }
```

The requestFile is instantiated with a proper working path for a file.
The path of that file begins exactly with what `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` returns.
I just cant understand what raises the error because everything seems to fit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide the complete logcat output?

Comment: This is the complete logcat: http://pastebin.com/xbyMewHc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> The path of that file begins exactly with what getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) returns.

AFAIK, that will not give you a directory named `SpCars_album/`.

> I just cant understand what raises the error because everything seems to fit.

The file you supplied is not one that can be served by the `FileProvider` from your defined roots.

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot that this is tied to [a documentation bug on `FileProvider`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61170). `FileProvider` and `<external-path>` does **NOT** serve files from `getExternalFilesDir()`, but instead from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. I created [a `StreamProvider` subclass that offers support for `getExternalFilesDir()`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider).

If you use my `StreamProvider`, replacing your `<external-path>` with `<external-files-path name="myexternalimages" path="Pictures/SpCars_album/" />`, you should have better luck.

Comment: Then assuming that the files I would like to serve are in the following path:
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mysecondapp/files/Pictures/SpCars_Album/'
What should I specify in my filepaths xml file?

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question now, but I've just had a similar issue.

A lazy solution I found is to just use:

```
<external-path name="myexternalimages" path="Android/" />
```

Because getExternalStorageDirectory returns "/storage/emulated/0/", sharing /Android (the next level down) will allow any files that are in your app to be accessed.

Alternatively, if you want to be more precise, you can do this:

```
<external-path name="myexternalimages" path="Android/data/YOUR_BUNDLE_ID/files/SpCars_album" />
```

This doesn't feel quite right, but it does seem to work!

Comment: @eAj: Worked like a charm - IOU a beer

Comment: Wait a second, the user clearly wants to use **getExternalFilesDirs**, NOT **getExternalStorageDirectory**.  So why should we specify `<external-path>` instead of `<files-path>`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky cause `<files-path>` is serves internal memory `files` directory `/data/data/BUNDLE/files` not external storeage

Answer (score 0):

Adding `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` into app gradlle dependencies worked in my case. 
Please change SDK platform version (28.0.0 in my case) accordingly.

Answer (score -8):

if you dont try catch exception as IllegalArgumentException for FileProvider.getUriFoFile(), when you run your code ,you also will have this exception.

```
try {
     Uri uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.fengfutong.bluetoothc2s.fileprovider", f);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```