# Camera intent failing

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

i am using this code to run a camera intent to take a photo. All being taken from [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) step by step (full sized camera option)

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
          // Create an image file name
          String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
          String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
          File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
          File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg",storageDir);

         // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
         mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return image;
    }
```

This is my `Manifest` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.terrormachine.swipeapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
         android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
         android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
         android:exported="false"
         android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
        </provider>

<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my paths xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

and i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.terrormachine.swipeapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20161015_211933_-593154643.jpg
```

A little surprising since the file "shell" is there(at this location). 
I fount [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455035/illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configuration-root-that-contains-xxx-on) thread but i cant understand a thing...can you explain it humanlike? Any solution is welcome! Its an important project and i need to finish as much as possible and this is a huge stop.

Comment: Update to the current version of the support libraries. Then, use `external-files-path` instead of `external-path`, replacing `path` with just `Pictures`. Also, [you need to grant permissions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html) on the `Uri`, otherwise the camera app the user chooses will not be able to use the `Uri`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) for an example of using `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, though I use internal storage, not external storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your files_path.xml, you need to replace **com.example.package.name** with your apps package name, as explained on developers site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.terrormachine.swipeapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Also add camera permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing "uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"" in your manifest.